# how fill department field in people and groups?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I am new to SharePoint and I am using Sharepoint 2013 can anyone help me about the department field in site setting > users and permission > people and groups?
how does this field fill?
how to define different department?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  Do you want to change a People and Group field?  This is accessible via Site Settings > Site Columns > then select your column > edit the choices you see there.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the user name->edit your profile->then you can set "department" for the user:

[image]

Then run "User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" timer job manually.

Now you can see the department field in people and groups.